# findOne() in spring boot ordered by Asc

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I' am trying to use findOne() jpa query, now it's working fine with me but I want also the result  `extDetl`  to come orderd by vaccineDose

```
    detlList.forEach(detl->{detl.setPersonId(resultDto.getPersonId());
            EnExternalDetails extDetl  = enExternalDetailsRepo.findOne(detl.getVaccinationId());
            
            if(extDetl!=null && !extDetl.getVaccineDose().equals(detl.getVaccineDose() )){
                String code = "3021";
                String msg = "Dose value not matching with the saved record";
                
            }
                });
```

the result will sucsses if

```
    "Details": [
        {
            "PersonId": 1,
            "vaccinationId": 15,
            "vaccineDose": 11
        },
        {
            "PersonId": 2,
            "vaccinationId": 14,
            "vaccineDose": 12
          
        }
    ]
```

but if it's like below it will show "Dose value not matching with the saved record"

```
    "Details": [
        {
            "PersonId": 2,
            "vaccinationId": 14,
            "vaccineDose": 12
        },
        {
            "PersonId": 1,
            "vaccinationId": 15,
            "vaccineDose": 11
          
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I think you should add ``vaccineDose`` in your query (in findOne) as well, instead of searching all records and then finding the matching one.

Comment: How is the output related to the code you showed? In the code you are loading single `EnExternalDetails` by id. There is no sense in ordering anything. Also nothing that you load in the code leaves the scope of the for each, so it is not related in any way to the output that happens somewhere.